# Multi lined Radio Button in Flask Form

Tags: python, flask, radio-button, flask-wtforms

I have the following in my Flask Forms file:

```
Question = RadioField("Line 1 \n Line 2 \n Line 3\n", 
           choices=[('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No')],
           validators=[DataRequired()])
```

It seems that the RadioField does not process \n because as it just shows up as "Line 1 Line 2 Line 3" all on the same line.

How can I make the RadioField question multi line? Or is this impossible to do just within the flask form code?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the html version "<br/>" instead of "\n"